# Inserting leading carriage return in sed append

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to insert some text after a string match using sed, and I'm having trouble getting a leading carriage return into the appended text.  I have ...

```
sed -i "/^#Comment to append text after/a \n[$username.conn]\nipAddress=$ipAddr\nportNumber=$portNum" file
```

And I would like a carriage return before that 3-line insert, so the output is ...

```
#Comment to append text after

[$username.conn]
ipAddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
portNum=yyyy
```

But putting a `\n` in front of `[$username.conn]` just results in a leading n...

```
#Comment to append text after
n[$username.conn]
ipAddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
portNum=yyyy
```

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: are you interpolating those variables or are they literally $username in the file after replacement?

Comment: I'm interpolating them.  They're assigned elsewhere in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the special handling of backslash in `sed`:

```
sed "/^#Comment to append text after/a\\\n[$username.conn]\nipAddress=$ipAddr\nportNumber=$portNum" input
```

or more clearly:

```
sed '/^#Comment to append text after/a \
\
['$username'.conn]\
ipAddress='$ipAddr'\
portNumber='"$portNum" input
```

Comment: Dang, who would've thought it would just take a ton of extra slashes to fix that problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but using `\\n` instead `\n` (just the 1st time) have worked for me.

Like this:

sed -i "/^#Comment to append text after/a **\\n**[$username.conn]\nipAddress=$ipAddr\nportNumber=$portNum" /usr/Jas/conf/drp.ini

I tried this on sed commnad from gnu.